# How to fire two triggers for two tables at different time to insert some values from both the tables to third table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have 3 tables in SQL server with following fields.

```
Table 1- id, name, age.
Table 2- id,email, Address.
Table 3- id, name, email.
```

I wish to use two triggers like, when I insert values on Table 1, `id` and `name` should insert in Table 3. When I insert values in Table 2, `Email` should insert in Table 3 and it should insert at `id` and `name` position means it should not show `NULL` values. `Name`,`id` and `email` should insert in one row.

Comment: do you have any any relationship in between table 1and table 2 ?

Comment: can you elaborate this which means what are the columns available in respective tables?

Comment: How do you know *which* row in `Table 3` an `email` inserted into `Table 2` should be applied to?

Comment: table 1 and 2 have one common field.

Comment: "table 1 and 2 have one common field" - is it a secret that you're not going to tell us? Because in your question, as it currently stands, no they do not. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i think i missed id in Table 2

Answer (score 0):

You should make the View for  inserting data from two tables to a single table

Comment: But i think its not possible to create triggers on view.(For triggers).i have tried to create trigger on view but it showing error 'Invalid object'.

Comment: @Harshit.k89 - you can create triggers on views, but I think smas's point is that you can *replace* table 3 with a view. Why do you want to *store* redundant information?

Comment: Yes.. There is an option but is this only an option?

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the data model so that it is normalized.  You wouldn't need a trigger to replicate data into Table 3 if the name and email columns weren't in 2 tables.